# How to use a string from another class in c# winform application?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms

So I am coding a winform app in Visual Studio C# which locks a users type message using a generated key. The user needs to know the date the key was created, which is collected from a file the program generates when the user types into "textBox1". What I am doing is using strings to verify the date the "password.txt" file is created, is the date the user puts in if not the message will not open. The problem though I am having trouble with static properties, this error:

Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Encryptor1.Encrypt(string)'  UniveralWindowsTextPGP  C:\Users\keife\source\repos\UniveralWindowsTextPGP\UniveralWindowsTextPGP\Form2.cs  85  N/A

Here is where I implement the encryption and decryption method:

```
namespace UniveralWindowsTextPGP
{
    class Encryptor1

    {
        public static string IV = "1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a";
        public static string Key = "1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a13";

        public static string Encrypt(string decrypted)
        {
            byte[] textbytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decrypted);
            AesCryptoServiceProvider endec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            endec.BlockSize = 128;
            endec.KeySize = 256;
            endec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
            endec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
            endec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            endec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform icrypt = endec.CreateEncryptor(endec.Key, endec.IV);
            byte[] enc = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textbytes, 0, textbytes.Length);
            icrypt.Dispose();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(enc);
        }

        public static string Decrypted(string encrypted)
        {
            DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\password.txt");

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\password.txt");
             var created = fi.CreationTime;
            if (fi.CreationTime != Form2.keyhere)
```

// The line above is where the error is occurring in this part.

```
{
                string message = "That is incorrect, access is denied.";
                MessageBox.Show(message);
            }
            else

            { 
                    byte[] textbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
                    AesCryptoServiceProvider endec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
                    endec.BlockSize = 128;
                    endec.KeySize = 256;
                    endec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
                    endec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
                    endec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    endec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    ICryptoTransform icrypt = endec.CreateDecryptor(endec.Key, endec.IV);
                    byte[] enc = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textbytes, 0, textbytes.Length);
                    icrypt.Dispose();
                    return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(enc);
                }
            
        }
    } }
```

// And here is the form:

```
  namespace UniveralWindowsTextPGP

{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void passwordbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Decrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dir = richTextBox1.Text;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("encryptedmessagehere.txt");
        string line = sr.ReadLine();

        richTextBox1.Text = Encryptor1.Decrypted(Convert.ToString(line));
    }

    private void Form2_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dir = richTextBox2.Text;




        string enctxt = Encryptor1.Encrypt(richTextBox2.Text);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\encryptedmessagehere.txt", enctxt);

    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void richTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox2.EnableContextMenu();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dir = richTextBox2.Text;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\encryptedmessagehere.txt");
        string line = sr.ReadLine();

        richTextBox2.Text = Encryptor1.Decrypted(Convert.ToString(line));
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\decryptedmessagehere.txt", line);
       
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.Show();

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form f4 = new Form4();
        f4.Show();

    }

    public void passwordbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       

    }

    private void richTextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string richTextBox3 = "";
    }

    public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("C:/password.txt");
        txt.Write(textBox1.Text);
        txt.Close();
        public string keyhere = textBox1.Text;
```

// This is where the error is occurring here.

Thank you very much, your thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: please do not provide your **entire** code, but only those parts that are relevant for your issue. Most of the code has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Try to pass as a new parameter instead of accessing directly. `public static string Decrypted(string encrypted, string textFromOtherClass)` and while calling it `richTextBox1.Text = Encryptor1.Decrypted(Convert.ToString(line), "passStringHere");` @keiferBly

Comment: Running it as public static string Decrypted(string encrypted, string Form2.textBox1) resulted in the text box not being found, is that what you meant? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. you cannot declare a class variable in a method.

This line here:

```
public string keyhere = textBox1.Text;
```

in `textBox1_TextChanged` method.

2. you are using the syntax for the access of a static variable in this line:

   if (fi.CreationTime != Form2.keyhere)

There is no static variable `Form2.keyhere`. this is why the compiler complains.

You could solve both problems by creating one:

```
public static string keyhere

public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("C:/password.txt");
    txt.Write(textBox1.Text);

    keyhere = textBox1.Text;

    txt.Close(); // write this as last call, otherwise textBox1 might already be disposed when you try to access textBox1.Text;
}
```

Disclaimer: this is an adhoc solution which violates the certain rules for clean coding. Especially the single responsibility principle. Preferably you would pass all necessary information into the `Decrypted` method and use it there. The class `Encryptor1` should not know anything about a `Form` or other UI elements.

Comment: I just did that thanks! But now on this code if (fi.CreationTime != string keyhere) in the  encryption, it returns "invalid expression term "string". I wonder why that might be....

Comment: @KeiferBly "But now on this code if (fi.CreationTime != string keyhere)" why would you change the if condition code? I gave you a solution to make your original if condition code working and you changed it and broke it again. The reason why the compiler complains is because you cannot declare a new variable in a comparison expression like `a != b` the declaration has to happen before that.

Comment: Oh sorry was trying to follow someone elses advice at  same time. Well I just changed the condition code back and use your solution, it fixed the static issue. But now in   if (fi.CreationTime != string Form2.keyhere); It's saying it expects a ) after Form2. I wonder why that might be...

Comment: @Keifer Bly You could remove the 'string', and there is no need to declare the type on the right side of ‘!=’. In addition, the return type of ‘fi.CreationTime’ is DateTime, you can try to convert it. As shown below:if ((fi.CreationTime).ToString()!=Form2.keyhere)